# How to update the values of one column's row where another column value matches specific value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe with four columns `id1`, `id2`, `config_type`, `call_frequency`, however, the `id1` and `id2` don't matter much.

I need to replace the value of the `call_frequency` column with a specific string where a condition matches another column.

**Input:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image: ![enter image description here]

Basically I need to replace the values in the corresponding `call_frequency` column when `config_types` are matched.

```
{'type2':'string2', 'type3':'string3', 'type4':'string4'}
```

and the non-matching values should be left untouched.

I tried:

```
df[df.config_type == 'dict_key', 'column'] = 'dict_value'
```

But it's giving me error.

> TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use `loc`.

```
d = {'type2':'string2', 'type3':'string3', 'type4':'string4'}
for k,v in d.items():
    df.loc[df.config_type==k, 'call_frequency'] = v
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative method using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

d = {'type2':'string2', 'type3':'string3', 'type4':'string4'}
df["call_frequency"]=np.where(df['config_type'].isin(d), df['config_type'].replace(d), df['call_frequency'])
```

Comment: This is the way to go, combine `where` and `replace`, I deleted my answer, this is still faster than using `loc`.

Comment: What is this `df['t2']` at the end?

Comment: @SukumarRdjf should be call_frequency